# Efficient way upload multiple files to separate locations on google cloud storage

Tags: google-cloud-storage, gsutil

Here is my case, I'd like to copy multiple files to separate locations on google cloud storage, e.g:

```
gsutil -m cp /local/path/to/d1/x.csv.gz gs://bucketx/d1/x.csv.gz
gsutil -m cp /local/path/to/d2/x.csv.gz gs://bucketx/d2/x.csv.gz
gsutil -m cp /local/path/to/d3/x.csv.gz gs://bucketx/d3/x.csv.gz
...
```

I have over 10k of such files, and executing them by separate calls of gsutil seems to be really slow, and lots of time is wasted on setting up network connection. What's the most efficient way to do that, please?

Comment: I tried linux `parallel` with `gsutil -m`, it seems to work fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your paths are consistently of the nature in your example, you could do this with one `gsutil` command:

```
gsutil -m cp -r /local/path/to/* gs://bucketx
```

However, this only works if you want the destination naming to mirror the source.  If your paths are arbitrary mappings of source name to destination name, you'll need to run individual commands (which as you note can be sped up with `parallel`).

Comment: I realize the problem with your command is that I only want to upload `x.csv.gz` under `/local/path/to`. There are many other files I don't want to transfer. `parallel` seems to work ok

Comment: If you just want to exclude files, you could consider using `gsutil rsync -x`

Comment: `gsutil rsync -x` is only helpful when the names of files to exclude have a small number of patterns.